# how can i git clone private repositoty? Error: Could not resolve host

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I found that I must use:

```
git clone https://myname:password@github.com/myname/repo.git
```

when I am cloning a private repo with git.

However, this doesn't work and the console says:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myname: Name or service not known
```

So I tried:

```
git config --global https.proxy http://myname:password@proxy.url
```

but it still doesn't work:

```
fatal : unable to access 'https://github.com/myname/repo.git': Could not resolve host: myname
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried with a public repo?

Comment: I want it to be private :(

Comment: I can understand that. I’m just asking if you’re having the same issue with non private repos.

Comment: When trying it with public repo, it just works well....(and I'm using window os whether it is important or not)

Comment: Try this. `git clone https://git-username@github.com/git-username/repo-name.git` and it should prompt for password. Also check `git config --list` and see if the username and email are set properly.

Comment: when i try  git clone https://git-username@github.com/git-username/repo-name.git
it just say repository not found...
and when try git config --list there is code "https~~~ " that I type before

Answer (score 0):

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname myname: Name or service not known

That means the URL used did not start with `https://`

> when I try `git clone https://git-username@github.com/git-username/repo-name.git` it just say repository not found

Then double-check the case (lowercase/upercase) of your URL